# Show the names of products (in first column) ordered along with their total amount sql

Tags: sql

I have two tables:

- `CUSTOMERS` (ID, FIRSTNAME, LASTNAME, ADDRESS);
- `ORDERS` (ID, PRODUCT_NAME, PRODUCT_PRICE, DATE_ORDER DATE, ID_CUSTOMER, AMOUNT);

Show the names of products (in first column) ordered along with their total amount. Please sort by first column.

```
Select product_name, amount
From orders
where amount = (Select SUM(amount) from orders)
order by product_name;
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: 1.By which column do you want to order? (perhaps both) ? ,  2.Why did you present the `customers` table ?

Answer (score 1):

You seem to need a simple aggregate query using `group by`. Your sub-query returns the same value for every row.

It's possible there is more to your question than you have alluded to since there is no use of your `Customers` table, so why even mention it?

```
Select product_name, sum(amount) TotalAmount
From orders
group by product_name
order by product_name;
```